# Why is my fixed-position element being pushed down?

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

I'm trying to put some text in the right side of the grid, but I have no idea why it's pushing down the background.

Maybe it is a problem with `::after`.

I don't mind any suggestions to change that as long as the background is split 50% 50%.

I really appreciate all your help!

```css
:root {
  --backColor: #F2F2EF;
  --mainColor: #37384E;
  --textColor: #9BBEC7;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'left right';
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

body {
  background: var(--backColor);
  margin: 0%;
}

body:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background: var(--mainColor);
}

.logo {
  margin: 0%;
  font-size: 60px;
  grid-area: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <p class="logo">jZ</p>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48074187/8620333 (you find easier way to set the coloration)

Comment: What do you ultimately want your page to look like? Can you include an image showing us what you're seeking? **Side note:** It's more typical to use the `fr` unit when setting grid proportions: `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

The basic problem is your rendering order.

The browser lays out your elements in this order:

1. The `body` element.
2. The `.grid-container` element.
3. The `body::after` pseudo-element.

The first thing to note is that your pseudo-element is rendered last. Why? Because it comes **`::after`** the `body` element.

By this time, the `.grid-container` element has already taken up its space, so the pseudo-element must appear on the next line.

The quick and simple solution to this problem is to switch from `::after` to `::before`, so the pseudo-element moves to first in the rendering order. Done!

### `::after` (original code)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'left right';
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

body {
  background: var(--backColor);
  margin: 0;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background: var(--mainColor);
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  grid-area: right;
}

:root {
  --backColor: #F2F2EF;
  --mainColor: #37384E;
  --textColor: #9BBEC7;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <p class="logo">jZ</p>
</div>
```

### `::before` (solution #1)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'left right';
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

body {
  background: var(--backColor);
  margin: 0;
}

body::before {  /* adjustment */
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background: var(--mainColor);
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  grid-area: right;
}

 :root {
  --backColor: #F2F2EF;
  --mainColor: #37384E;
  --textColor: #9BBEC7;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <p class="logo">jZ</p>
</div>
```

### But the pseudo-element has a fixed position. Why does it recognize the space of the `.grid-container`?

- With `position: fixed` an element is removed from the document flow. Its [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) is the initial containing block which, for all intents and purposes, is equivalent to the viewport.
- The CSS [offset properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props) (`top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`), which control the placement of elements that are absolutely-positioned (including fixed positioning), have an [initial value](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props) of `auto`. **This means that the element remains in the same place where it would normally be if it were in the document flow.**
- Said another way, when you set an element to `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, you're specifying the type of positioning you want... *but you're not positioning it anywhere.*
- It isn't until you define the offsets that the element is actually positioned.
- In this case, that means that the `::after` element, appearing below `.grid-container` for reasons described above, can be shifted into place with `top: 0`.

### `::after` with `top: 0` (solution #2)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'left right';
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

body {
  background: var(--backColor);
  margin: 0;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background: var(--mainColor);
  top: 0; /* new */
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  grid-area: right;
}

:root {
  --backColor: #F2F2EF;
  --mainColor: #37384E;
  --textColor: #9BBEC7;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <p class="logo">jZ</p>
</div>
```

### `.grid-container::after` (solution #3)

Yet another solution involves applying the pseudo-element to `.grid-container` instead of `body`. Now the fixed position element is rendered as a child of the grid container and before the `body` element closes. Both `::after` and `::before` solve the problem.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'left right';
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

body {
  background: var(--backColor);
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background: var(--mainColor);
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  grid-area: right;
}

:root {
  --backColor: #F2F2EF;
  --mainColor: #37384E;
  --textColor: #9BBEC7;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <p class="logo">jZ</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your pseudo element (:after) has a fixed position, you will need something to work as a reference from where it should be positioned. Add "top: 0" to it and it should work.