# Overlaying an Image between two background colors in CSS

Tags: css

My html is like

```
<div style='bg-gray'>
</div>
<img src='sample.png'>
<div style='bg-white'>
</div>
```

my css is like

```
.bg-gray{
  background-color:gray;
}
.bg-white{
  background-color:white;
}
```

How can I make an image overlay between two colors like the sample image?

[image: sample img]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48074187/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a simple example for you.
I did the following

Changed `style=` to `class=` style is only used for inline styles.
I added the class `.block` to the divs so you can target them together

I moved the `img` to the first block so you can set it relative to that container (also why I added `position: relative` to the `.block` class

After that I absolutly position the image relative to it's parent. Because i know the image is going to be 150px height I can give it `bottom: -75px` to place it halfway.
Then I've added `left: 50%; transform: translatex(-50%);` to position in the abosolute middle of the container.

`z-index: 2;` is so it comes behind the second `.block`

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -75px;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.bg-gray{
  background-color:gray;
}
.bg-white{
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class='block bg-gray'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'>
</div>
<div class='block bg-white'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I couldn't think the position settings before. Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **:after Selector** :-

```css
.container{ padding:50px; height:300px;display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; position:relative; z-index:5;}
.image-card{ position:relative;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); text-align:center;}
.image-card:before{content:''; position:absolute; left:0px; width:100%; background:#99FFCC; height:50%; bottom:0px;}
```

```html
<div class="image-card">
<div class="container"><img src='' width="200" height="200" style="background:#00CCFF;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Before & After selector could be also the solution. Helped me a lot :)